# Linear Programming Question regarding shipping costs with books

Tags: linear-programming

A publisher has orders for 600 copies of a certain text from San Franciso and 400 copies from Sacramento. The company has 700 copies in a warehouse in Novato, and 800 copies in a warehouse in Lodi. It costs 5 dollars to ship a text from Novato to San Francisco, but it costs 10 dollars to ship it to Sacramento. It costs 15 dollars to ship a text from Lodi to San Francisco, but it costs 4 dollars to shop from Lodi to Sacramento. How many copies should the company ship from each warehouse to San Francisco and Sacramento to fill the order at the least cost?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_{ij}$ the amount of copies, which are shipped from warehouse $i$ to city $j$.

$i=1, \ \texttt{ if copies are transported from Navato}$

$i=2, \ \texttt{ if copies are transported from Lodi}$

$j=1, \ \texttt{ if copies are transported to San Francisco}$

$j=2, \ \texttt{ if copies are transported to Sacramento}$

*First constraint: 600 copies are needed in San Francisco*

$x_{11}+x_{21}=600$

*Second constraint: 400 copies are needed in Sacramento*

$x_{12}+x_{22}=400$

*Third constraint: At most 700 copies can be shipped from warehouse in Navato*

$x_{11}+x_{12}\leq 700$

*Fourth constraint: At most 800 copies can be shipped from warehouse in Lodi*

$x_{21}+x_{22}\leq 800$

The total costs of shipping have to be minimized:

$\texttt{min} \ \ 5 \cdot x_{11}+10\cdot x_{12}+15\cdot x_{21}+4\cdot x_{22}$

And finally the non-negative constraint:   $ \ x_{ij}\geq 0 \quad \forall i,j$

If the solution is not an integer, don´t worry about it. Just round the results.